# Cant rebuild My electron App After Installing sqlite3 module

Tags: node.js, npm, sqlite, electron

When I am trying to rebuild my code with the command "electron-rebuild -f -w sqlite3". I am getting this error on windows.

```
An unhandled error occurred inside electron-rebuild
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@3.7.0
gyp info using node@8.11.3 | win32 | x64
gyp http GET https://atom.io/download/electron/v2.0.5/iojs-v2.0.5.tar.gz
gyp http 200 https://atom.io/download/electron/v2.0.5/iojs-v2.0.5.tar.gz
gyp http GET https://atom.io/download/electron/v2.0.5/SHASUMS256.txt
gyp http GET https://atom.io/download/electron/v2.0.5/win-x64/iojs.lib
gyp http GET https://atom.io/download/electron/v2.0.5/win-x86/iojs.lib
gyp http 200 https://atom.io/download/electron/v2.0.5/SHASUMS256.txt
gyp http 200 https://atom.io/download/electron/v2.0.5/win-x64/iojs.lib
gyp http 200 https://atom.io/download/electron/v2.0.5/win-x86/iojs.lib
gyp info spawn C:\Python27\python.EXE
gyp info spawn args [ 'C:\\Users\\company             ismi\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\electron-rebuild\\node_modules\\node-    gyp\\gyp\\gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-f',
gyp info spawn args   'msvs',
gyp info spawn args   '-G',
gyp info spawn args   'msvs_version=auto',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\App\\node_modules\\sqlite3\\build\\config.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\company ismi\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\electron-rebuild\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\company ismi\\.electron-gyp\\.node-    gyp\\iojs-2.0.5\\common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=C:\\Users\\company ismi\\.electron-    gyp\\.node-gyp\\iojs-2.0.5',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=C:\\Users\\company ismi\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\electron-rebuild\\node_modules\\node-gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=C:\\Users\\company ismi\\.electron-    gyp\\.node-gyp\\iojs-2.0.5\\<(target_arch)\\iojs.lib',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=C:\\App\\node_modules\\sqlite3',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\App\\node_modules\\sqlite3\\build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.' ]
gyp info spawn C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe
gyp info spawn args [ 'build/binding.sln',
gyp info spawn args   '/clp:Verbosity=minimal',
gyp info spawn args   '/nologo',
gyp info spawn args   '/p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x64' ]
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
C:\App\node_modules\sqlite3\build\deps\action_before_build.vcxproj(20,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error:     `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe` failed with exit     code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Users\company ismi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\electron-rebuild\node_modules\node-    gyp\lib\build.js:262:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit     (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17134
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\company ismi\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\electron-rebuild\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--target=2.0.5" "--arch=x64" "--dist-url=https://atom.io/download/electron" "--build-from-source" "--module_name=node_sqlite3" "--module_path=C:\\App\\node_modules\\sqlite3\\lib\\binding\\electron-v2.0-win32-x64" "--host=https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com" "--remote_path=./{name}/v4.0.2/{toolset}/" "--package_name=electron-v2.0-win32-x64.tar.gz"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\App\node_modules\sqlite3
gyp ERR! node -v v8.11.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.7.0
gyp ERR! not ok

Failed with exit code: 1

Error: gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@3.7.0
gyp info using node@8.11.3 | win32 | x64
gyp http GET https://atom.io/download/electron/v2.0.5/iojs-v2.0.5.tar.gz
gyp http 200 https://atom.io/download/electron/v2.0.5/iojs-v2.0.5.tar.gz
gyp http GET https://atom.io/download/electron/v2.0.5/SHASUMS256.txt
gyp http GET https://atom.io/download/electron/v2.0.5/win-x64/iojs.lib
gyp http GET https://atom.io/download/electron/v2.0.5/win-x86/iojs.lib
gyp http 200 https://atom.io/download/electron/v2.0.5/SHASUMS256.txt
gyp http 200 https://atom.io/download/electron/v2.0.5/win-x64/iojs.lib
gyp http 200 https://atom.io/download/electron/v2.0.5/win-x86/iojs.lib
gyp info spawn C:\Python27\python.EXE
gyp info spawn args [ 'C:\\Users\\company 
ismi\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\electron- 
rebuild\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\gyp\\gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-f',
gyp info spawn args   'msvs',
gyp info spawn args   '-G',
gyp info spawn args   'msvs_version=auto',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\App\\node_modules\\sqlite3\\build\\config.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\company     ismi\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\electron-rebuild\\node_modules\\node-    gyp\\addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\company ismi\\.electron-gyp\\.node-    gyp\\iojs-2.0.5\\common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=C:\\Users\\company ismi\\.electron-    gyp\\.node-gyp\\iojs-2.0.5',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=C:\\Users\\company     ismi\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\electron-rebuild\\node_modules\\node-    gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=C:\\Users\\company ismi\\.electron-gyp\\.node-gyp\\iojs-2.0.5\\<(target_arch)\\iojs.lib',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=C:\\App\\node_modules\\sqlite3',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\App\\node_modules\\sqlite3\\build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.' ]
gyp info spawn C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe
gyp info spawn args [ 'build/binding.sln',
gyp info spawn args   '/clp:Verbosity=minimal',
gyp info spawn args   '/nologo',
gyp info spawn args   '/p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x64' ]
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel     build, please add the "/m" switch.
C:\App\node_modules\sqlite3\build\deps\action_before_build.vcxproj(20,3):     error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
```

gyp ERR! build error
   gyp ERR! stack Error: 
   `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
    gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Users\company ismi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\electron-rebuild\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:262:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17134
gyp ERR! command "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\company ismi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\electron-rebuild\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--target=2.0.5" "--arch=x64" "--dist-url=https://atom.io/download/electron" "--build-from-source" "--module_name=node_sqlite3" "--module_path=C:\App\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\electron-v2.0-win32-x64" "--host=https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com" "--remote_path=./{name}/v4.0.2/{toolset}/" "--package_name=electron-v2.0-win32-x64.tar.gz"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\App\node_modules\sqlite3
gyp ERR! node -v v8.11.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.7.0
gyp ERR! not ok

Failed with exit code: 1
    at SafeSubscriber._error (C:\Users\company ismi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\electron-rebuild\node_modules\spawn-rx\lib\src\index.js:277:84)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (C:\Users\company ismi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\electron-rebuild\node_modules\rxjs\Subscriber.js:242:16)
    at SafeSubscriber.error (C:\Users\company ismi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\electron-rebuild\node_modules\rxjs\Subscriber.js:201:26)
    at Subscriber._error (C:\Users\company ismi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\electron-rebuild\node_modules\rxjs\Subscriber.js:132:26)
    at Subscriber.error (C:\Users\company ismi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\electron-rebuild\node_modules\rxjs\Subscriber.js:106:18)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (C:\Users\company ismi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\electron-rebuild\node_modules\rxjs\Subscriber.js:132:26)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (C:\Users\company ismi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\electron-rebuild\node_modules\rxjs\Subscriber.js:106:18)
    at SafeSubscriber._next (C:\Users\company ismi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\electron-rebuild\node_modules\spawn-rx\lib\src\index.js:251:65)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (C:\Users\company ismi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\electron-rebuild\node_modules\rxjs\Subscriber.js:242:16)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (C:\Users\company ismi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\electron-rebuild\node_modules\rxjs\Subscriber.js:189:22)

How do i fix that. But The same application is working fine under the Mac System.
Please Guide me to fix this error.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to build for both x86 and x64 arch? And please format the question correctly. Looks like node-gyp is using some data from local cache. Have you tried cleaning AppData folder?

Comment: @Jis 
C:\Users\<User Name>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules.
Delete only relevant modules that may cause a problem.
But before that, make sure that you have visual studio 2017 installed and ensure you're following the build instructions as mentioned here.
https://electronjs.org/docs/development/build-instructions-windows

Answer (score 0):

What I would do:

1. Go to the folder where sqlite3 is located e.g. ./node_modules/sqlite3 .
2. Ensure that for MS Windows you have installed the visual studio compiler and python.
3. Edit ./node_modules/sqlite3/package.json and add a new entry in the scripts section:

   "build_vcust": "node-pre-gyp rebuild --target=X.X.X --arch=x64 --dist-url=https://atom.io/download/electron --msvs_version=2015"

   Note: Replace X.X.X with your electron version.
4. From the sqlite3 folder execute "npm run build_vcust".

Learn more at (reference): https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/tutorial/using-native-node-modules.md